# What is reversible heat?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, reversibility

If found the following question while studying thermodynamics.

[image]

What is meant by "reversible heat" and when would it be a thermodynamic property (and when it wouldn't). I am not asking for the solution. I'd like to know what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the definition of $Q_R$.

From what I read, reversible heat seems to mean $TdS$. Thermodynamic property probably means "differential of a state variable" or equivalently "exact differntial". If so, the question is just maths. It's about proving the differential $TdS$ is not exact.

Note : "reversible heat" is an extremely confusing expression about $TdS$ imo.